# Albert: Why are some applications not shown in the results?

Tags: albert

I realized that some of the apps installed on my system are not accessible using albert. Why do they not show up when I query them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) defines which applications shall be shown. If the desktop entry contains the key value pair `NoDisplay=true`, the application will not be shown. Further the keys `OnlyShowIn` and `NotShowIn` define which desktop environments should (not) show the desktop entry. The values are compared to the environment variable `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.